# iOS - SWRevealViewController pass data to from right to left controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

im working with SWRevealViewController to display a right controller. The left controller is the main. I have a button that when pressed, will slide in right controller.

On the right controller, onButton clicked, how do i pass data to the left controller?

I have found some sample and tried the following code but its not working:

```
   // Update value on product left view controller
    LeftViewController *lvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftViewController"];
    lvc.badge.value = 12;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:lvc animated:YES];
```

I also tried prepareForSegue but it didn't work:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"swLeft"]) {
        LeftViewController *lvc = (LeftViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        lvc.badge.value = 12;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have the same question.. if u have the answes pls post

Comment: Hi i havent found the ans myself